# Laravel Intellisense / autocomplete with PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

Trying to get a clean environment to work on Laravel 5.4 / PhpStorm.
Followed all the instructions from: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper (including installing the PhpStorm Laravel plugin)

Got the file`_ide_helper.php` generated, added

```
Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
```

to its proper location, cleared cache, restarted...

Please look at attached image, is the lack of intellisense I get supposed to be fixed by the ide helper ?

[image]

Comment: Ask laravel-ide-helper for details. For example: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/431 . Possibly you have imported the facade -- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/431#issuecomment-275898789

Comment: That should be it, so what should I replace 'use ....' with ?

Comment: As per dev comment (2 comments below) -- remote that particular `use ....` entry completely? -- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/431#issuecomment-275904348 . Hopefully laravel-ide-helper author will clarify somewhere how to use it with Laravel 5.4 (if there is such need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution, assuming you have installed the helper already:

Example:

Replace in a controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

by

```
  use Validator
```

In your config/app.php you must have this alias:

```
'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
```

In my case it was already there.

After this, no more error message for the example shown in the image above and I can use full power of phpstorm that correctly understands the ::make method.

Source https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/431#issuecomment-275898789 thanks @lazyone.