# Laravel PhpStorm autocomplete

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, phpstorm

I am having problems with autocompletion in PhpStorm using Laravel. I have set up the IDE accordingly from this guide:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

I cannot autocomplete basic functions like `Input::only` or `Input::has`. The closest answer I can find is in this thread:

[Laravel Intellisense / autocomplete with PhpStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41955136/laravel-intellisense-autocomplete-with-phpstorm)

However, Input is already added as alias in `config/app.php` - still not working.

Anyone experienced same problem and/or know a solution to this?

EDIT:

Sorry for not providing code example - it's only been some Laravel trial and error, but here goes:

I have the route:

```
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@authenticate');
```

In the action of the controller I have tried the following:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
   public function authenticate(Request $request) {

       Input::get(); // <-- autocompletes
       Input::has(); // <-- NO autocomplete

       $request->only(); // <-- autocompletes
       $request->validate(); // <-- NO autocomplete

   }
}
```

Comment: This forum is really for help with coding challenges, read this over: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide some basic code sample where it does not work (simple code but whole file, so we can see what `use` you have got there etc).

Comment: If you're using ide helper and have generated the phpstorm meta then it might be better to use `request()->only|input|..` instead of `\Input::`. I would personally discourage the use of aliases as they often lead to this sort of issue

Comment: I hope you have generated IDE-helper files using ide-helper package (as per that tutorial). It works just fine here. E.g. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;`  .. and then just use `$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);` As for `Input` -- use `$request` (Laravel can easily inject it into your controller) .. or `request()` if you  prefer / to complicated or do not know what I mean.

Comment: *"In the action of the controller I have tried the following:"* Just use `$request`, it's always better to use provided parameter over some behind the scene magic.

Comment: Because of quite a lot of magic involved in Laravel (e.g. `Macroable` trait), it all just about what methods are declared in PHPDoc comments for those classes and what laravel-ide-helper can provide on top. If you look at how `Input` facade is declared (I mean PHPDoc for that class) you will not find `has()` method there. If you look at class behind `$request` you will also not find `validate()` method there. It's all about having a better PHPDoc in Laravel or better extra doc provided by ide-helper package. IDE works with the sources it is given, and so far it does a good job.

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, makes sense the IDE Helper can get no better than the PHPDoc is. From Laravel's side it's a shame though. Autocompletion is really the key to full benefit of a frameworks features. Thanks for the clearification!

Answer (score 2):

use laravel [ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package

it can provide accurate `autocompletion`. Generation is done based on the files in your project.

> phpstrom support auto-complete best thing is that